# How to call dynamic subroutine in a loop

Tags: perl

Can any one help to find easy way to call subroutines in a loop?
Now, I called them as below manually. How do I do that programmatically?

```
&case1Validate($fTxt);
&case2Validate($fTxt);
&case3Validate($fTxt);
&case4Validate($fTxt);
&case5Validate($fTxt);
&case6Validate($fTxt);
&case7Validate($fTxt);
&case8Validate($fTxt);
&case9Validate($fTxt);
&case10Validate($fTxt);
```

Comment: A relevant structure you might want to lookup to solve this is a *Dispatch Table* (any search engine should give you plenty of results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the function name into a variable first, and then turn off [`use strict 'refs'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). After that, you can call it using the ampersand `&`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub case1Validate { return $_[0] }
sub case2Validate { return $_[0] }
sub case3Validate { return $_[0] }

for my $i ( 1 .. 3 ) {
    no strict 'refs';
    my $sub_name = 'case' . $i . 'Validate';
    CORE::say &{$sub_name}( $i );
}
```

This program will output

```
1
2
3
```

Make sure to disable `strict 'refs'` in the smallest possible scope. If you do not turn it off, you will get the error

> Can't use string ("case1Validate") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use

Note that this is just one of several solutions, and in most cases it should not be the preferred one. It's better to create a [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) (or a list of code refs, [like Dave explains in his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970438/1331451)) because that way you have better control over what happens inside your program.

Since you're iterating a list of functions now you can use [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) to check if they exist before calling them.

```
&{ $sub_name }( $i) if exists &$sub_name; # both &{} and & are fine
```

The same should be done with a dispatch table where you create the keys on the fly.

Comment: There is a reason this stuff exists. I don't see any problems with making things a bit more dynamic, if that kind of thing is called for. I'd appreciate an explanation of the downvote.

Comment: I'm the downvoter, and my answer is the explanation. I don't believe the OP should be encouraged to use indirect references when the same thing can be achieved just as easily in a `strict`-compliant fashion, particularly when they're already using Perl4 conventions (prefixing sub calls with `&`), which suggests that a) they're still learning the language and b) they're learning from sources which do not follow current best practices.

Comment: @Dave I thought so. I did want to point out that the ampersand is bad, but I forgot. I agree that your solution is viable. Maybe include a link to an explanation of a _dispatch table_, which I believe is relevant. Depending on the actual situation of the OP, using a hash with code refs and dispatching instead of iterating might be the best solution. In any case, I think it's useful to have an answer that explains how this is possible. I'll add bit of warning to it.

Comment: Yes, agreed that dispatch tables are a more generally useful tool than arrays of coderefs.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @DaveSherohman: What do you think a *dispatch table* has that isn't provided by an *array of coderefs*?

Comment: Funny how the two answers are developing.

Comment: @Borodin: Dispatch tables are "very useful in cases where you might not want to call every sub every time, and always in the same order". But I suspect you're trying to prompt me to add something more detailed. Any specific pointers to what you think is missing?

Comment: @DaveSherohman: Not at all. I'm wondering why you think an array of subroutine references isn't a dispatch table, and how a dispatch table is "more useful".

Comment: @Borodin: OK, frame shift for me, then. I associate the term "dispatch table" specifically with hashes (or hash-like structures in non-Perl contexts) and have never considered that an array might also qualify, but you're right that it's not really all that different. But your asking about "more useful" had me fighting to resist the urge to expand my (hash-based) dispatch table example into a minimalist plugin framework...

Comment: @DaveSherohman: [*Wikipedia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table) says that *"In computer science, a dispatch table is a table of pointers to functions or methods"*. So basically it's an array of subroutine references. It's irrelevant whether the table is indexed by an integer or a string. This reminds me of the frustrating misuse of  *associative array* to mean a hash table, when an ordinary integer-indexed array is "associative".

Comment: Arrays aren't [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) because you can't add/remove key->val mappings to/from an array.

Answer (score 9):

`strict 'refs'` complains about indirect references ("using a variable as a variable name") for a reason.  Several reasons, in fact, most of them having to do with indirect references reducing your ability to debug and maintain your code.

The better way to do this is to create an array of code references and iterate over that, calling each in turn:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub case1Validate { return 'Case 1: ' . $_[0] }
sub case2Validate { return 'Case 2: ' . $_[0] }
sub case3Validate { return 'Case 3: ' . $_[0] }

my @validators = (\&case1Validate, \&case2Validate, \&case3Validate);

for my $sub (@validators) {
  say $sub->('foo');
}
```

Another technique, which is very useful in cases where you might not want to call every sub every time, and always in the same order, is to use a hash as a *dispatch table*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub case1Validate { return 'Case 1: ' . $_[0] }
sub case2Validate { return 'Case 2: ' . $_[0] }

my %validators = (
  case1 => \&case1Validate, 
  case2 => \&case2Validate, 
  # If the sub is small and you're not using it separately, you can even define
  # it in-line!
  case5 => sub { return 'Case 5: ' . $_[0] }
);

for my $i (1 .. 5) {
  # Because of "exists", will only attempt to print for cases 1, 2, and 5,
  # since cases 3 and 4 don't exist
  say $validators{"case$i"}->('foo') if exists $validators{"case$i"};
}
```

Comment: I was looking at your answer earlier this morning, but objected with the first solution, where the validators were still "hardcoded", the OP asked for a dynamic solution. The second example at least has `$validators{"case$i"}->('foo')` which indicates some shape of dynamicness (did I just come up with that word ?) through `$i`